# How to find the tolerable overlap between 2 arrays of x,y coordinates in python (numpy)

Tags: python, performance, numpy

I have two 2-D arrays of different length. How can I find the overlap of these arrays along the zeroth axis, within a certain tolerance ? For example if

```
a1 = [1,1.2]
a2 = [1,2.1]
a3 = [1,1.1]
a4 = [.89, 2.21]
a5 = [0,0] 
coors1 = np.array( [ a1, a2 ])
coors2 = np.array( [ a3, a4, a5 ])
```

then I want a function `overlap` that gives

```
overlap( coors1,coors2, tolerance=0.1)
#[ [1,1.2] ]
overlap( coors1, coors2, tolerance=0.12)
#[ [ 1,1.2], [1, 2.1] ]
```

I came up with something like

```
def overlap(coor1, coors2, tolerance ) :
    return [ c1 for c1 in coors1 for c2 in coors2 if np.all( np.isclose( c1, c2, atol=tolerance))   ]
```

but it seems like it could be slow...

### For those who are interested and care to chime in

My question stems from some database work I am doing. I have several databases which have x,y coordinates each as columns. There are also columns representing various measurements performed at those coordinates. I need to compare the databases based on the coordinates, taking into account that some of the coordinates were subject to floating point rounding errors.

Comment: Did you make an attempt?  Please post that and ask question(s) about its deficiencies

Comment: Working on it, will post

Comment: So, finally it's supposed to select rows from `coors1`?

Comment: This is probably unrelated to your issue, but be warned that `0.1` is a notoriously badly represented floating point number. For instance, `0.1 + 0.2` is not `0.3` (but rather `0.30000000000000004`).

Comment: this is actually the source of my problem, most of the coordinates are equal, however some are off by some small floating point

Comment: @dermen Are you sure about the added code? It gives same output with those two tolerances.

Comment: @Divakar I updated the values for the coordinates themselves, try re-pasting. Sorry about the confusion, I am having trouble adding today

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got the question correctly, you can use [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to solve it in a vectorized fashion -

```
def overlap(coors1, coors2, tolerance ):

    # Perform elementwise absolute subtractions between input arrays 
    sub_abs_vals = np.abs(coors1[None,:,:] - coors2[:,None,:])

    # Check for ANY equality along 0-th axis & ALL equality along 2-nd axis.
    # Return the corresponding row from first input array.
    return coors1[np.all(np.any(sub_abs_vals<=tolerance,axis=0),axis=1)]
```

Verify results -

```
In [124]: coors1
Out[124]: 
array([[ 1. ,  1.2],
       [ 1. ,  2.1]])

In [125]: coors2
Out[125]: 
array([[ 1.  ,  1.1 ],
       [ 0.89,  2.21],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  1.06]])

In [126]: def overlap1(coors1, coors2, tolerance ) :
     ...:     return [ c1 for c1 in coors1 for c2 in coors2 if np.all( np.isclose( c1, c2, atol=tolerance))   ]
     ...: 
     ...: 
     ...: def overlap2(coors1, coors2, tolerance ):
     ...:     sub_abs_vals = np.abs(coors1[None,:,:] - coors2[:,None,:])
     ...:     return coors1[np.all(np.any(sub_abs_vals<=tolerance,axis=0),axis=1)]
     ...: 

In [127]: overlap1(coors1, coors2, 0.1 )
Out[127]: [array([ 1. ,  1.2])]

In [128]: overlap2(coors1, coors2, 0.1 )
Out[128]: array([[ 1. ,  1.2]])

In [129]: overlap1(coors1, coors2, 0.12 )
Out[129]: [array([ 1. ,  1.2]), array([ 1. ,  2.1])]

In [130]: overlap2(coors1, coors2, 0.12 )
Out[130]: 
array([[ 1. ,  1.2],
       [ 1. ,  2.1]])
```